# Trisection of a line segment in hyperbolic space

Tags: geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

- In euclidean space, it is possible to bisect a line segment (using a compass and a straightedge). This is also true in hyperbolic space.
- In euclidean space, it is also possible to trisect a line segment (using a compass and a straightedge).

Is this also true in hyperbolic space? If so, how would it be possible?

If not, is there such proof that shows *why* hyperbolic line segment trisection is impossible?

Comment: My purely heuristic argument of why it can’t be done: first, in spherical geometry, you can’t trisect a line (great-circle) segment because that amounts to trisecting an angle. Second, the hyperbolic plane is “just like” the sphere except that certain signs are reversed. Since it’s impossible in spherical geometry, you expect impossibility in hyperbolic geometry.

Comment: @WillJagy I'd appreciate if you just told me where in the article my question is answered, instead of making me have to read the entire thing.

Comment: @Lubin Considering a compass & a straightedge aren't useful, are there other tools that can be used to trisect a hyperbolic line segment?

Comment: The only approach I know would be coordinatization-dependent and analytic. I’m sure this is not the sort of tool you were thinking of.